# How to get the width of a photo taken in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following code to take a picture in Xamarin:

```
MediaFile photo = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions()
{
    SaveToAlbum = true,
    Name = fileName                
});
```

However, after I've taken the picture, I want to retrieve the width of the image. I thought there might be a:

```
photo.Width
```

But there is not. There is a `PhotoSize` property on the `StoreCameraMediaOptions`, but that appears to be a way to dictate the size, rather than retrieve it.

Is there a way to do this in Xamarin, or an existing plug-in that will accomplish it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `FFImageLoading` the `ImageInformation` class gives you the original height & width,
you could assign a mediafile to an image then get the width of that image that rendered the mediafile

```
   var image = new CachedImage()
    {
        Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => photo.GetStream())
    };

    image.Success += (sender, e) =>
    {
         var h = e.ImageInformation.OriginalHeight;
         var w = e.ImageInformation.OriginalWidth;
     };
```

Hope this one might helps.

Comment: I did consider this, but I need the size of the original image. As I understand it, this will give me the size of the image as it appears on the screen.

Comment: It'll give you original size. Also you can call it without using any view: ImageService.Instance.LoadStream(...).Success(info => { //info.OriginalHeight etc }).PreloadAsync

Answer (score -1):

*Here you go this might help you...*

```
public static Size GetImageSize(string fileName)
        {
            #if __IOS__
            UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile(fileName);
            return new Size((double)image.Size.Width, (double)image.Size.Height);
            #endif

            return Size.Zero;
        }
```